# how to run 2 crawlers from the same python script

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio, scrapy

I have two python crawlers who can run independently.

crawler1.py
crawler2.py

They are part of an analysis that I want to run and I would like to import all to a commong script.

```
from crawler1.py import * 
from crawler2.py import *
```

a bit lower in my script I have something like this

```
if <condition1>:
    // running crawler1 
    runCrawler('crawlerName', '/dir1/dir2/')

if <condition2>:
    // running crawler2 
    runCrawler('crawlerName', '/dir1/dir2/')
```

runCrawler is :

```
def runCrawler(crawlerName, crawlerFileName):
    print('Running crawler for ' + crawlerName)

    process = CP(
        settings={
            'FEED_URI'   : crawlerFileName,
            'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'
        }
    )

    process.crawl(globals()[crawlerName])
    process.start()
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: ReactorAlreadyInstalledError
reactor already installed
```

The first crawler runs ok. The second one has problems.
Any ideas?

I run the above through a visual studio debugger.

Comment: WHen you launch a new crawler it is trying to create it's own twisted reactor, which after the first one will always fail.  Better to have 2 spiders from 1 crawler

Comment: any way I can clear the environment ? 
I need to specify different filenames for output. would that be possible ?

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do it is this way

your code should be

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging


# your code




settings={
            'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'
        }
process = CrawlerRunner(Settings)

if condition1:
    process.crawl(spider1,crawlerFileName=crawlerFileName) 
if condition2:
    process.crawl(spider2,crawlerFileName=crawlerFileName)

d = process.join()
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()  # it will run both crawlers and code inside the function
```

your spiders should be like

```
class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider1"
    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI'   : spider1.crawlerFileName}
    def start_requests(self):
            yield scrapy.Request('https://scrapy.org/') 

    def parse(self, response):
        pass
```